# VSTS Release Management UI : Color coding for environments or a way to group environments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am in the process of setting a Continuous Deployment pipeline in VSTS.

We have three environment groups : Dev, PPE, Prod. Deployment proceeds from Dev to PPE to Prod provided that the everything is healthy with the previous environment group.

Each of these environment group consists of multiple physical environments or ARM template deployments.

How do I group multiple environments together in VSTS RM ? Is there a way of color coding environments or snapping them together in one box ?

[image]

Also, looks like there is a way of "Moving up/down" the environment if there are two in parallel. However if there is just one, it snaps to the top. It would be cleaner if it stayed in its "track". See the dotted line in above picture.

Comment: You should submit feature requests on User Voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now there is no such settings to achieve it in VSTS release definition.

I posted an user voice [Enable to group environment together in release definition](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33262603-enable-to-group-multiple-environments-together-in) for this feature, you can vote and follow up.